# Is there a efficient PySpark/Python equivalent to Scala's Seq.fill()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, functional-programming

I am trying to create large randomly generated data using PySpark. The Scala code below is essentially what I am going for but I can not figure out an efficient way to replicate the seq.fill() in PySpark.

```
def randomStringGen(length: Int) = scala.util.Random.alphanumeric.take(length).mkString

val df = sparkContext.parallelize(Seq.fill(4000){(randomStringGen(4), randomStringGen(4), randomStringGen(6))}, 10).toDF("col_1", "col_2", "col_3")
```

Sure, I can write a for loop or list comprehension but I know this is very inefficient. Is there a way I can rewrite this in Python or PySpark that will take advantage of Spark's parallelism?

```
data = [randomStringGen(4) for x in range(4000)]
df = spark.CreateDataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Overview

If you want Spark to do most of the work, you shouldn't create the data in the driver and then parallelize it. Instead, let Spark generate plenty of rows with looped joins or `explode()` and then apply your random string function as a UDF.

## Step 1

Create seed DataFrame with just 1 row filled with sample data.

```
columns = ["rnd1", "rnd2", "rnd3"]
initial_data = [("0000", "0000", "0000")]
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(initial_data).toDF(*columns)
```

## Step 2

You can double the rows joining with an auxiliary DataFrame with 2 rows.

```
df_doubler = sparkSession.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,)]).toDF("aux")
```

## Step 3

The join to double the rows looks like:

```
df = df.join(df_doubler, lit(True), "inner").select(*columns)
```

So you have to repeat that several times (`iterations`) inside a loop:

```
target_rows = 4000
iterations = math.ceil(math.log2(target_rows)) # iterations = 12, enough because 2^12 = 4096 >= 4000

for i in range(iterations):
    df = df.join(df_doubler, lit(True), "inner").select(*columns)

df = df.limit(target_size) # Cut rows to target size
```

So far, we've avoided uploading many rows from the driver. If your target number of rows is really big, you can explore other join or explode based solutions. Consider doing a `repartition()` now or inside the loop if the rolling DataFrame `df` seems skewed.

## Step 4

Time to apply randomization. The work will be done in parallel by nodes:

```
my_udf = udf(lambda x: randomStringGen(x))
df = df.withColumn("rnd1", my_udf(4))
df = df.withColumn("rnd2", my_udf(4))
df = df.withColumn("rnd3", my_udf(4))
```

---

*Disclaimer*: I don't have access to a pyspark IDE so check syntax.